# Посчитать количество подчиненных у сотрудника с помощью Count() OVER()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Есть запрос:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, 
       e.last_name, 
       d.department_name,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY E.MANAGER_ID)
  FROM employees e 
  JOIN departments d 
    ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = D.MANAGER_ID 
 ORDER BY D.DEPARTMENT_ID;
```

Можно ли как-нибудь посчитать количество подчиненных у сотрудника с помощью `COUNT(*) OVER()` ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос пример входных данных, и что вы хотите получить. Мне например не понятно, какая у вас модель данных и что вы хотите тут посчитать.

Comment: @Viktorov Это стандартные [схемы с примерами данных](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/toc.htm), в данном случае HR. Думаю, их то уж описывать не стоит.

Comment: когда то давно я их даже смотрел, но это не значит, что я их помню. Если не трудно, сделайте все же минимальный пример

Answer (score 3):

Можно конечно. Всё почти правильно, только связь:

```sql
JOIN departments d ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = D.MANAGER_ID
```

покажет какой отдел находится в подчинении. А нужно подчинённые сотрудники, т.е связь *1:m* с таблицей `employees` (*self-join*). Как то так:

```sql
select 
    e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id,
    s.employee_id, s.last_name, s.manager_id,
    count (*) over (partition by s.manager_id) subordinates
from hr.employees e 
join hr.employees s on s.manager_id = e.employee_id
```